# Не получатся запустить Fragment из адаптера RecyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragment, recyclerview, recyclerview.adapter

Есть код класса `NameListHolder`, находящегося в адаптере `RecyclerView`

```
class NameListHolder(val binding: NameListItemBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

    fun bind(paginationLocalModel: PaginationLocalModel, position: Int, context: NameListFragment){

        binding.name.text = paginationLocalModel.name
        itemView.setOnClickListener{

            val fragment = DescriptionFragment()
            val bundle = Bundle()
            bundle.putInt("position", position)
            fragment.setArguments(bundle)

            val activity=context.context as AppCompatActivity
            activity.supportFragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.rd_fragment, fragment)
                .commitNow()

            Log.d("OnClick", "произошло нажатие по позиции $position")
        }

    }

}
```

Внутри `itemView.setOnClickListener` должен запускаться фрагмент, но, по какой-то причине, он не запускается.

Вся цепочка передачи данных:

`NameListFragment`:

```
class NameListFragment : Fragment() {

...

    private fun initRecyclerExchangeRate(){
    
        binding?.listNameRV?.layoutManager =
            LinearLayoutManager(context)
        nameListAdapter = NameListAdapter(this)
    
        binding?.listNameRV?.adapter = nameListAdapter
    }

...

}
```

`NameListAdapter`:

```
class NameListAdapter(var context: NameListFragment
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<NameListAdapter.NameListHolder>() {

...

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: NameListHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(pagination[position], position, context)
    }

...


    class NameListHolder(val binding: NameListItemBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
    
        fun bind(paginationLocalModel: PaginationLocalModel, position: Int, context: NameListFragment){
    
            binding.name.text = paginationLocalModel.name
            itemView.setOnClickListener{
    
                val fragment = DescriptionFragment()
                val bundle = Bundle()
                bundle.putInt("position", position)
                fragment.setArguments(bundle)
    
                val activity=context.context as AppCompatActivity
                activity.supportFragmentManager
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.rd_fragment, fragment)
                    .commitNow()
    
                Log.d("OnClick", "произошло нажатие по позиции $position")
            }
    
        }
    
    }

...

}
```

Запуск первого фрагмента из `Activity` производится внутри разметки:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/rd_fragment"
    android:name="com.sem.receivedata.presentation.NameListFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

`DescriptionFragment.kt:22` указывает на строку     `val position: Int = bundle!!.getInt("position", 0)` внутри фрагмента `DescriptionFragment`

`NameListAdapter.kt:49` указывает на строку `val fragment = DescriptionFragment()` внутри `NameListHolder`

`Unknown Source:0` и `Unknown Source:4` всегда указывают на 0 и 4 строку, не зависимо от того, что там находится

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.sem.receivedata, PID: 5484
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sem.receivedata.presentation.DescriptionFragment.<init>(DescriptionFragment.kt:22)
        at com.sem.receivedata.presentation.adapters.NameListAdapter$NameListHolder.bind$lambda-0(NameListAdapter.kt:49)
        at com.sem.receivedata.presentation.adapters.NameListAdapter$NameListHolder.$r8$lambda$FuXGFWDKhm2ZD3YhtF7Xh98aUvc(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.sem.receivedata.presentation.adapters.NameListAdapter$NameListHolder$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onClick(Unknown Source:4)
```

Comment: Сомневаюсь, что фрагмент в разметке можно заменить. Попробуйте завернуть его во `FrameLayout` и в `replace` дать `id` этого `FrameLayout`

Comment: теперь, при нажатии на элемент вылетает ошибка `NullPointerException` (более подробно добавил в текст вопроса)

Comment: @woesss, а можно ли не привязывать запуск фрагмента к разметке `Activity`? (удалил строку `android:name="com.sem.receivedata.presentation.NameListFragment", чтобы запустить `Fragment` в коде `Activity``, но все классы `Binding` тут же выделились красным)

Comment: Можно. Для этого нужно вообще убрать тег `<fragment>...</fragment>`, вместо него поставить контейнер, а в коде ставить фрагмент через `FragmentManager`. NPE у вас потому что вы пытаетесь получить аргументы в конструкторе фрагмента, но задаёте то вы их после его вызова. Обращайтесь к аргументам там, где хотите использовать переданное, либо получите их в подходящем колбеке, например `onCreate()`